# Can i pass a string as a delimiter for bufio.ReadString()?

Tags: go

I have a file which contains multi-line queries. I wanted to read them one by one and print them. Something like :

temp.sql

```
select * from table1;  
select *  
from table2;

select 1;
```

Since i can have multiline queries I wanted to use ;\n as the delimiter. Is that possible ? Is there a better method that i can use instead of `bufio.ReadString` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

firstly, the prototype of `bufio.ReadString` is

```
 func (b *Reader) ReadString(delim byte) (line string, err error)
```

it can only take one byte as arg, so your `;\n` delimiter won't work.

**use `;` as delimiter instead.**

But if you use `ReadString(';')` it will contain other characters in your results, such as '\n'

a example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    const raw = `select * from table1;  
select *  
from table2;

select 1;`

    br := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(raw))

    var err error
    var s string
    err = nil
    for err == nil {
        s, err = br.ReadString(';')
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%q", s)
        }

    }
```

this will get:

```
"select * from table1;""  \nselect *  \nfrom table2;""\n\nselect 1;"
```

[online test](https://play.golang.mx/p/ec55b4cb503dd5f959667f2db51db11998e85402)

**Solution:**

use `Scanner` may be more convenient, and achieve this as bellow.

ps: `;` will be considered as part of words

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    const raw = `select * from table1;  
select *  
from table2;

select 1;`

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(raw))
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    var tmpbuf bytes.Buffer

    for scanner.Scan() {
        w := scanner.Text()
        tmpbuf.WriteString(w)
        if w[len(w)-1] == ';' {
            tmpbuf.WriteString("\n")
            fmt.Printf(tmpbuf.String())
            tmpbuf.Reset()
        } else {
            tmpbuf.WriteString(" ")
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
    }
}
```

you will get:

```
select * from table1;
select * from table2;
select 1;
```

[online test](https://play.golang.mx/p/5ae9c5ab8fe632c3a185dcd42a7beacf5ec38ee7)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bufio.Scanner` for that: https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner
See the lines example: https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines